# php timeout with file_get_html

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i been trying to fetch some data from wikia website by using simple_html_dom lib for php. basically what i do is to use the wikia api to convert into html render and extract data from there. After extracting, i will pump those data into mysql database to save. My problem is that, usually i will pull 300 records and i will stuck on 93 records with file_get_html being null which will cause my find() function to fail. I am not sure why is it stopping at 93 records but i have tried various solution such as

```
   ini_set( 'default_socket_timeout', 120 );
   set_time_limit( 120 );
```

basically i will have to access wikia page for 300 times to get those 300 records. But mostly i will manage to get 93 records before file_get_html gets to null. Any idea how can i tackle this issue?

i have test curl as well and have the same issue.

```
function test($url){
 $ch=curl_init();
 $timeout=5;

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

 $result=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $result;
 }

 $baseurl = 'http://xxxx.wikia.com/index.php?';

 foreach($resultset_wiki as $name){
  // Create DOM from URL or file
 $options = array("action"=>"render","title"=>$name['name']);
 $baseurl .= http_build_query($options,'','&');
 $html = file_get_html($baseurl);
 if($html === FALSE) {
 echo "issue here";
 }
  // this code for cURL but commented for testing with file_get_html instead
  $a = test($baseurl);
  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load($a);

    // find div stuff here and mysql data pumping here.
 }
```

$resultsetwiki is an array with the list of title to fetch from wikia, basically resultsetwiki data set is load from db as well before performing the search.

practically i will it this type of error

```
  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in
```

Comment: did you try to use `curl` all through out instead?

Comment: yes i did, but i will still get the same result of hitting null issue on record 93. is like no different without using curl.

Comment: Isn't the website just throttling you because you're sending out a large number of calls to them in a very short time period?

Comment: anyway in solving that?

Answer (score 0):

answered my own issue, seems to be the URL that i am using and i have changed to curl with post to post the action and title parameter instead